# How to assign new master database in a geo distributed MongoDB cluster?

Tags: mongodb, replication, distributed, database-replication, master-slave

I need to have MongoDB databases in different data centers. One MongoDB database will be a master in a main data center and other will be slaves in other data centers. How can we assign a new master database in different data centers if our master database in the main data center will die?

Comment: Are you talking about having a single replica set distributed between data centers?  If so, I don't think that's a very good idea.

Comment: Why don't you think so? If somebody write something into database in USA I need to be able to read this value in Europe with minimum latency. Is it a bad idea to have replica in different data centers?

Comment: Nodes in replica sets need to constantly send data between themselves to keep all nodes updated.  If this communication goes over the internet, it could slow down the entire replica set, particularly when doing writes.  If your data needs are very heavy on reads rather than writes, then perhaps it won't be so bad.  You may want to look into tag aware sharding as a practice:  https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/#customized-data-distribution-with-tag-aware-sharding

Comment: But sharding are using for distribute data to several nodes. It don't help for many reads. I still need to be able to read data locally. I think it is bad idea to read data from USA if you sit in Europe. I don't know any other ways to read data with low latency (locally).

Comment: Mongo is nice because it allows you to make decisions such as these based on your data needs.  It's flexible.  You need to decide between having high chatter between nodes on a single replica set spread out across continents, or having the latency of realtime reads from nodes on other continents.  Fortunately, Mongo gives you the choice.  Here's a whitepaper I found, but haven't read, that looks like it may cover some of the tradeoffs you'll have to make decisions about:  https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/mongodb-multi-data-center-deployments  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean a distributed replica set between data centres, the other nodes will elect a new master if the master should fail.

If you have a preference for what node should become the new master, then it is possible to configure a preference for this case.

I suggest you read up the section on [Replica set elections](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) in the MongoDB Docs for more information.